How to turn on network proxy for mitmproxy on Windows 10
I'm looking to turn on the network proxy (pointing to http://localhost:8080) via command line for mitmproxy use.
I've tried:
set http_proxy=http://localhost:8080
netsh winhttp set proxy localhost:8080

Unfortunately , neither of the above commands seem to work and traffic in not being routed through mitmproxy.
However, when I manually toggle the network proxy in Settings > Network > Proxy, everything works perfect and traffic is being routed through mitmproxy.
How do I start the network proxy via commandline/ssh in such a way that would route traffic through mitmproxy?
Many thanks
